# Subversive and Subclipse both in eclipse at same time how to disable one or the other?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, subclipse, subversive

In Eclipse Kepler apparently somehow I managed to install both versions into eclipse.  So on "import" for instance there are two SVN entries one is "Project from SVN" the other is "Checkout Projects from SVN".  I probably don't want that!  How can I get rid of one of them (**and how can I tell which I am using?**).  In "show views" I have TWO SVN items:

```
SVN
    Revision Properties
    SVN Locks
    SVN Properties
    SVN Repositiries
    SVN Repository Browser
SVN
    Merge Results
    SVN Annotate
    SVN Properties
    SVN Repositories
    SVN Rev Properties
    SVN Tree Conflicts
```

In installed Software I see:

```
Subclipse (Required 1.10.3)
Subclypse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional) 3.0.0
Subversion Client Adapter (required) 1.10.1
Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.8.5
Subversion Revision Graph 1.1.1
SVNKit 1.8.3 Implementation (Optional) 3.0.5.I20140122-1700
SVNKit Client Adapter (Not Required) 1.8.0.1
```

I have Oracle ADF Tools and I think that may have been how I ended up with all this.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Ansi Console    1.2.1.201311171914
CollabNet Merge Client  4.0.2
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers  2.0.1.20130919-0803
GlassFish Tools 6.3.0.201312191402
Java EE 5 Documentation 6.3.0.201312191402
Java EE 6 Documentation 6.3.0.201312191402
Java EE 7 Documentation 6.3.0.201312191402
Java Source Attacher Feature    1.2.3.0
JavaHL 1.8.5 Win64 Binaries (Optional)  3.0.5.I20140122-1700
Maven SCM Handler for Subversive    0.13.0.201302121311
Native JavaHL 1.8 Implementation (Optional) 3.0.5.I20140122-1700
Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.4) 6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.5) 6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.6) 6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle ADF Documentation (11.1.1.7) 6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle ADF Documentation (12.1.2)   6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle ADF Tools    6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle Cloud Tools  6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle Coherence Tools  6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle Database Tools   6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle Java EE Tools    6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle Maven Tools  6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle WebLogic Scripting Tools 6.3.0.201312191402
Oracle WebLogic Server Tools    6.3.0.201312191402
StartExplorer  Feature  1.5.1
Subclipse (Required)    1.10.3
Subclipse Integration for Mylyn 3.x (Optional)  3.0.0
Subversion Client Adapter (Required)    1.10.1
Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter    1.8.5
Subversion Revision Graph   1.1.1
SVNKit 1.8.3 Implementation (Optional)  3.0.5.I20140122-1700
SVNKit Client Adapter (Not required)    1.8.0.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details, select the software you no longer want and click Uninstall.

For more details look at [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in?)

**Update**

The first item is subversive:

[image: Subversive]

The second is subclipse

> ```
> SVN
>   Merge Results
>   SVN Annotate
>   SVN Properties
>   SVN Repositories
>   SVN Rev Properties
>   SVN Tree Conflicts
> ```

I would be you, I would uninstall both of them, and reinstall the only one I'm interested in, to be sure to have a clean, working plugin, just in case removing a plugin would break anything in the other one.

Comment: Yes, but which is which?